# can't deal with this association - django app

Tags: django, django-models, uml

hope you are doing well !

I don't know what to do in this case, this is the association I want to create

[image: UML]

*an activity itself can have 0 till many activities* ,

this is **models.py** the attribute are just an examples

```
class Activity(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField()
        a_id = models.Foreignkey(a, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

can anyone guide me ?, thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is specified in the [documentation of a **`ForeignKey`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey):

> To create a **recursive relationship** – an object that has a many-to-one relationship with itself – use `models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE)`.

You thus can pass a `'self'` string to refer to itself:

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    parent = models.Foreignkey(
        'self',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='children'
    )
```